# Can I zoom an SVG sample object to fill its container

Tags: canvas, svg

We have a big SVG object which we've fragmented into little pieces.

Most of these little pieces have an large offset to ensure when all the pieces are put back together they form the full picture.

What I'm wondering is; is there an easy way to take a single, tiny piece, measure its extent and then zoom in on it so it fills the SVG container...

Basically, I'm trying to show one tiny cell of a big puzzle, full-screen..

We're trying to do this in browser so we're looking for .js / svg solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getBBox()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox) to get the bounding box of any SVG element. You can then use that to set the [`viewBox`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) attribute on the `svg` root element.

You won't really have to worry about scaling, because the [`preserveAspectRatio`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) attribute will take care of that.

You might also be interested in [SVG views](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#LinksIntoSVG).

Here's a little example for good measure. It will zoom to the blue square after 2 seconds, pan and zoom to the red square when you click on the blue one, and zoom out again when you click on the red square:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <rect id="blue" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue"/>
    <rect id="red" x="100" y="100" width="50" height="50" fill="red"/>

    <animate id="pan" attributeName="viewBox" begin="blue.click" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>
    <set attributeName="viewBox" to="0 0 200 200" begin="red.click"/>

    <script><![CDATA[
    setTimeout(function(){
        var rect = document.getElementById('blue').getBBox();
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('viewBox', rect.x + ' ' + rect.y + ' ' + rect.width + ' ' + rect.height);
    }, 2000);

    var pan = document.getElementById('pan');
    var rect = document.getElementById('red').getBBox();
    pan.setAttribute('to', rect.x + ' ' + rect.y + ' ' + rect.width + ' ' + rect.height);
    ]]></script>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Jim I've added a little example to illustrate as well now.